# SQL Select only duplicates from one column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, duplicates

I have a query that produces a table like this:

```
BN      System  amount
13098   System1 860.05
16722   System1 63360
16722   System2 1544713.19000001
01292   System2 3260
17133   System2 6240
33851   System2 155340.03
24638   System2 11364.54
89936   System1 3719.85
57522   System2 50153558.7400001
84197   System2 6175
81568   System2 57402.05
99029   System2 59108.88
97532   System1 880
13283   System2 16745.51
51553   System2 26222
77632   System2 9202.5
84314   System2 185750
84314   System1 233766.5
```

Here is the query I use to get this table:

```
select 
    BN,
    System,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM 
    tbl1
group By
    BN,
    System
```

I want to select the rows that have duplicate BNs only.

For example, I want to return on when BN = 16722 and BN = 84314.

How can I do that?

I tried using

```
Having count(BN) > 1
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.bn, t.system, sum(t.amount)
  from tbl1 t
  join (select bn from tbl1 group by bn having count(distinct system) > 1) x
    on t.bn = x.bn
 group by t.bn, t.system
```

I think by 'duplicate' you mean the same BN value is associated with 2+ unique systems?

The above should work if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by system)) as cnt
      from tbl t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

This is particularly useful if you really are using a subquery.  This formulation only runs the subquery once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using `exists`.

```
select bn, system, sum(amount)
from tbl1 t1
where exists (select 1 from tbl1 t2 
    where t1.bn = t2.bn and t1.system <> t2.system)
group by bn, system
```